# file_get_contents() stopped working

Tags: php, undefined, file-get-contents, offset

I have my PHP file on a free web hosting site and the code bellow suddenly stopped working with an error:

```
$data = file_get_contents("http://eqafe.com/inventories/$name/inventory_by_slug.json") or die(print_r(error_get_last()));
```

Error output:

```
Array ( [type] => 8 [message] => Undefined offset: 6 [file] => /usr/lib/php/head.php [line] => 90 ) 1
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: this error in not belong to `file_get_contents` .. check ur head.php file

Comment: Is it possible for me to access this file when I am using a free web hosting site (ServersFree.com)? I can't find it in my upload directory.